# Check each data column(s) for null is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have `dt` in which there are 4 rows and 35 columns. So I want to check for each row whether there is `null` value supplied or not. If `null` is supplied then break the condition if not then go ahead. So I tried the code below, but it's not working and is accepting the `null` values as well.

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["SAP_ID"] != DBNull.Value || row["CITY"] != DBNull.Value || row["FINAL_SR_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["FINAL_SO_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["INVOICE_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["IP_ID"] != DBNull.Value || row["APPLICABLE_MSA"] != DBNull.Value || row["SITE_CATEGORY"] != DBNull.Value || row["ID_OD"] != DBNull.Value || row["RFI_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["BILL_START_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["BILL_END_DATE"] != DBNull.Value || row["NO_OF_OPCO"] != DBNull.Value || row["ACTUAL_RENT_AMT"] != DBNull.Value || row["TENURE"] != DBNull.Value || row["GSM_ANTENNA_EXC_SAIL"] != DBNull.Value || row["GSM_ANTENNA_NOTEXC_SAIL"] != DBNull.Value || row["REV_TOT_CNT_GSM_ANTENNA"] != DBNull.Value || row["MW_ANTENNA_OF_UPTO06_DIA"] != DBNull.Value || row["MW_ANTENNA_OF_12DIA"] != DBNull.Value || row["MW_ANTENNA_OF_GREATER12_DIA"] != DBNull.Value || row["HEIGHT_OF_HEIGHEST_ANTENNA"] != DBNull.Value || row["WEIGHT_OF_TOWER_TOP_BTS"] != DBNull.Value || row["WIND_SPEED"] != DBNull.Value || row["POWER_RATING_OF_BTS"] != DBNull.Value || row["FLOOR_SPACE_INDOOR"] != DBNull.Value || row["FLOOR_SPACE_OUTDOOR"] != DBNull.Value || row["EB_STATUS_VALUE"] != DBNull.Value || row["NO_OF_US"] != DBNull.Value || row["HIGHER_RENT"] != DBNull.Value || row["RRH_COUNT"] != DBNull.Value || row["VOLUME_DISCOUNT"] != DBNull.Value || row["VENDOR_NAME"] != DBNull.Value || row["CIRCLE"] != DBNull.Value || row["APPLICABLE_SITE_RENT"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        ... // do something here
    }
    else
    {
        ... // do something here
    }
}
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: why are you not checking for `row["SAP_ID"] != null`?

Comment: @Daniel:  like only null ?? can u show for one sample

Comment: Your if condition performs to check is there any column is not null, then proceed. I don't it matches with your requirement. So probably these are 2 approaches: 1. Replace `!=` with `==`. 2. Use AND operator `&&` instead of OR operator `||`.

Comment: @YongShun : when I debugged the code, I found for `row["FINAL_SR_DATE"]` its coming as `{}` whenever there is blank column. so with what condition I should check. Please provide a sample code

Comment: How is this related to Excel in the first place? Excel isn't a database. If you use the Access engine to read it you can filter nulls in the SQL statement. If you use ExcelDataReader and eg `AsDataSet` you can specify which rows to include/exclude based on their values *before* you create the DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Long story short

`||` -> `&&`

## Explanation

You are asking whether

> x differs from null or y differs from null or ...

When does this evaluate to true? **This is true if and only if AT LEAST one of the operands differ from null**. As a result, you will either have to check whether

> x differs from null and y differs from null and ...

or, alternatively:

> not (x is null or y is null or ...)

The underlying logic is either to check whether **everything** differs from `null` or it's false that any of them is `null`.

Comment: dear Lajos, how can I check in my case ?

Comment: @Nad in your if replace the `||` operator to `&&`

Comment: @Nad every single `||` should become a `&&`.

Comment: @Nad currently you check whether at least one element differs from null. This will fail if you have some null values, but a field is not null, as you want to ensure that all the fields are differing from null.

Comment: Thanks Lajos, simply changing to `&&` from `||` worked. +1 for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

```cs
if (row["SAP_ID"] != DBNull.Value || row["CITY"] != DBNull.Value /* || Following columns */)
```

The above `if` statement is checking whether there is any column(s) contain value, which contradicts your requirement:

> If null is supplied then break the condition if not then go ahead

---

**Approach 1**: Check all columns contain value

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["SAP_ID"] != DBNull.Value && row["CITY"] != DBNull.Value /* && Following columns */)
    {
        // All columns are with value
    }

    // TO-DO
}
```

Or

**Approach 2**: Check any column(s) without value

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["SAP_ID"] == DBNull.Value || row["CITY"] == DBNull.Value /* || Following columns */)
    {
        // There are column(s) without value
    }

    // TO-DO
}
```